# Bootstrap 3 modal window does not display

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap 3 (full version) and I use bootstrap modal in my code:

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="deleteMessage" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Удалить</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="deleteMessage" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This code I copied from official docs, but it's not working, modal window does not display.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to change your anchor code into:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteMessage" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Удалить</a>
```

It looks like there is a typo in the tutorial, there should be additional "#" in the `data-target` attribute.

Comment: Perfect.  This is the key:  data-target="#deleteMessage"

Comment: Just added `#` to `data-target="#deleteMessage"` and it works! Thank you @fascynacja!

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to include `#` into `data-target` attribute

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteMessage" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Удалить</a>
```

[Live DEMO](http://bootply.com/85981)